# Customize People address book to show group description

Tags: 2016, sharepoint-on-prem, people-picker, spgroup

We are using SP2016 on-premise. Is there any way I can show the attribute of SharePoint groups (e.g. group description) in People picker address book?

The problem is our workflow need to assign to a group while our group names are too general (e.g. team1, team2, team3). Our users may pick the wrong sp group.  Therefore we would like to show the group description text,  or list the team members in the address book to facilitate "group" picking.

Answer (score 1):

Absolutly, showing the users Group property is pretty simple if you are familiar with item display templates. Adding the additional user property "Group" is also pretty simple but in most cases the hard part is 1) getting the users to update this property or sync it from AD property and 2) ensure the data quality of this property as group names changes over time and people moves from one group to another ( which is why products like HyperFish exists)

Perhaps the guide could give you a good basis :https://www.hyperfish.com/employee-directory

Comment: We cannot update the AD due to company policy.  Therefore we create sp groups (team1, team2..etc) . I would like to show the group description in ppl picker address book,  or list out the group members in people picker address book.

Comment: I updated my question to clarify my situation,  thx

Comment: Does people picker address book have its own display template?

Comment: Not really, no. In search resultats we can modify the item display templates as required but people picker is a speciel case. I suggest having a look at https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/use-the-client-side-people-picker-control-in-sharepoint-hosted-sharepoint-add-in